# <input> and <select> inside one <label> tag

Tags: html, input, label

Currently we have a input and a select inside a label.
We want to make the entire label clickable, so that this will select the radio button.
After selection the radio button, the underlaying div will show up where the user can use the select.

This code works great on Safari and Chrome, but not on Firefox.
In Firefox the user can not use the select, this will directly popback up.

How can we fix this problem?

```
<label class="formListBlock">
  <input id="method" value="<?php echo $_code ?>" type="radio" onclick="payment.switchMethod('<?php echo $_code ?>')" checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="radio"/>
  <div class="formListBlock-selector">
     <ul class="form-list ops-form-list" id="payment_form_ops_iDeal" style="display:none;">
        <li>
        <select name="payment" id="ops" class="required-entry">
        <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('--Please Select--')?></option>
            <?php foreach ($issuers as $key => $value): ?>
                <option value=<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($key) ?>>
                    <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($value) ?>
                </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</label>
```

Comment: You might consider adding some web-related tags like HTML.  I have little experience in web-development, but others with that experience might find your question more easily if you add the web tags, or re-title your question.

Comment: why don't you just put the label around the input? that would solve your problem.

Comment: may trying to add the label, radio and select into a span/div (for containing them inside the li), and then into the label tag, insert the attribute "for=id" and add that id into the radio. that makes that when label is clicked, radio is un/checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you put such complex HTML inside a `<label>`? Normally, a `<label>` just needs a `for=` attribute to point to the `id` of an `<input>`. This should be enough to make the input get focus when the user clicks the label. You can bind to the focus event and continue from there.

Comment: Tried that, but the underlaying div only appears when the radio is selected. And that will put the div outside the entire label. We want to keep this div inline with the radio button.